# Calcule the phase of the moon based on the date

Tags: excel, phase

I'm working on a project and need to associate the phase of the moon with each date I have. I would like to have 1= new moon, 2= first quarter, 3= full moon and 4= last quarter.
I work in Excel and I tried several times before asking but the results were wrong if I check some of my results.
Can you help me? I have 1500 observations and it is not possible for me to write them by hand.

I use this:**=MOD(INT((B2-DATE(2000;1;6))/27,3);4)+1**
B2 is my date and January 6, 2000 was the new moon.
The formula subtracts the known new moon date and divides by the average lunar month length, taking the integer part. Then, it takes the remainder when dividing by 4 and adds 1 to get the moon phase (1 for new moon, 2 for first quarter, 3 for full moon, and 4 for last quarter).
I also tried with 29.53 for the lunar month because on the web I could find both options for the lunar month.

[calendar explaining phases of the moon in relation to dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHUif.jpg)

Comment: Which date are you testing and what is the expected result?

Comment: I'm testing the date like this example: 22/09/2020 (from 2017 to 2023) and I want a result that is a number from 1 to 4 depending on the moon phase that was on the expected date

Comment: Which phase is that date though? (expected result)

Comment: There are some references [here](https://www.cloudynights.com/topic/819594-excel-formulas-for-moon-illumination-and-position/) and [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1709/formulas-to-determine-the-illuminated-phase-and-orientation-of-the-moon)

Comment: I am working in Namibia. I was therefore using the Moon phases calendar from Windhoek (https://www.timeanddate.com/moon/phases/namibia/windhoek). In this web site, the calendar is split into four phases. Each of these phases will be linked with a number (1= new moon, 2= first quarter, 3= full moon and 4= last quarter). For example, 7 Jan 2023 is Full Moon and 15 Jan 2023 is Third Quarter. This means 7, 8, 9 and 10 are number 3 (full moon) and 12, 13, 14 and 15 are 4 (thrid quarter). I split the days between these two day. 11 Jan 2023 is really between 7 Jan and 15 Jan.

Comment: I add a picture of a calendar to be more precise

Answer (score 0):

This one will work, with latest new moon as reference:

```
=INT((MOD((B2-DATE(2024;1;11));29.53059))/29.53059*4)+1
```

Success

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).